# gwt internet explorer inline style

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

I have a GWTt application, it works very well with Firefox and chrome but with IE it is not working properly. Some extra styles added to a verticalpanel(table for html) by IE not me. That extra style breaks my style and appearance of my application. When I look into style with ie developer tool, the extra style is seemed like below

```
inline style
   filter: opacity:1; ZOOM:1;
```

Why does IE do this and what can I do for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As @jonasr already noted, the problem is due standards mode and certain panels that you use.

Since you have declared `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your html document, the browser is put in standards mode.

As the link explains: some "old" panels (old, as in before GWT 2.0), in your case VerticalPanel, do not render properly in standards mode. You should instead use FlowPanel.

About IE adding styles - since GWT produces different output for different browsers (works around browser bugs and quirks), it's entirely possible that the style you mention was added by GWT.

Comment: I tried flowpanel and it is same again. Any suggestions can you give?

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific about which version of GWT and IE you are talking about, and which doctype you are using.
But I would advise you to read [this](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Standards). If your application is in Standards Mode, it is expected that vertical panels will not layout properly. Check that you have the correct doctype.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

 - Gwt version : 2.1.0 
 - IE version  : IE8

In my *.html file I use <!DOCTYPE html> but actually I couldn't understand your question "which doctype you are using", I just use doctype just like I mentioned above. I read document, you posted and I think I don't use Standart Mode because I use doctype declaration.

Am I wrong?

Thankss.